# What do we achieve by using PAM symbols symmetrical with respect to 0?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, symmetry

I can't seem to find the answer to this one anywhere online. We want them symmetrical with respect to 0 and also at even distance between each other. Why is this important?

Comment: because otherwise, there will be DC that contains no information but energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @AlexTP's comment (and @MBaz's excellent answer!):

The power spectrum of a modulated, pulse-formed signal is [1, p. 207]:

$$\Phi_{vv}(f) = \frac{\sigma_i^2}T \left\lvert G(f)\right\rvert^2 + \frac{\mu_i^2}{T^2}\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{\left\lvert G \left(\frac mT\right)\right\rvert^2}\delta\left(f-\frac mT\right) \tag{4-4-18}$$

with $G$ being the pulse shaping filter's frequency domain representation, $T$ being the symbol period, and most importantly, $\sigma_i^2$ and $\mu_i$ being the variance and the mean of info symbols, respectively.

Notice how the second, discrete-spectrum part disappears for $\mu_i=0$! Not only are you saving yourself a DC component, you're also avoiding unnecessarily adding out-of-band spurs.

So, from an information-theoretic point of view, a non-zero mean means wasting power without transporting information. From a spectrum regulation point of view it means introducing spurs even outside the the actual bandwidth of the information signal.

Since these spurs actually stem from a sampling of the pulse shape $G$ at multiples of the symbol rate, this is not as bad for many (especially purely theoretic) digital systems, where you have intense control over the parameters of that pulse shape – but if your pulse shaper is an imperfect analog one,  this will come back and bite you. Also note that if you're building a digital transmitter with a rectangular pulse shape with one sample per symbol (as found in many cheap transmitters), you *will* have a DAC somewhere. That DAC *will* have a reconstruction filter. You will have to incorporate that filter's imperfections as periodically repeating spur. Not great.

---

[1] Proakis: *Digital Communications*, third ed., published by McGraw Hill 1995.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of error for PAM depends on the distance between symbols. This means that the following two PAM constellations, both with distance $2$, will have the same probability of error:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}_1 &= \lbrace 2, 4 \rbrace \\
\mathcal{A}_2 &= \lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace
\end{align}

When using $\mathcal{A}_1$, the average energy spent per transmitted symbol is $(4+16)/2=10$ joules per symbol. When using $\mathcal{A}_2$, however, the average energy is $(1+1)/2=1$ joule per symbol: ten times less.

Even if transmitting a signal with constant DC (as pointed out by @AlexTP) were not a problem, you still want to use constellations that are symmetrical around zero because they minimize the energy expenditure for a given BER.

A good and simple excercise is to prove that this is true in general, and not just for the example I provided.